# Algorithm to fill non-rectangular 2D tile-space with smaller 2D tile-based shapes

Tags: c#, algorithm, shapes

I am trying to figure out how I would go about writing algorithm (in C#) that, when given:

- A set of generally small tile-based shapes. Often 2x2, but not always. Sometimes the shapes will be 2x1 or non-rectangular.
- A tilemap (two-dimensional array) in which certain tiles are marked "free" and certain tiles are "reserved". The free tiles designate the area where the tile-based shapes are allowed to go, the reserved tiles cannot be occupied by the shapes.

Example of a tile-based shape, other than 2x2s:
http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/9057/awk.png

An example of "available space" in a tilemap:
http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/8263/spaceh.png

- The white in this image designates the space to be filled, but I want the algorithm to be able to work just as well if the gray were the space to be filled and the whites were reserved.

Basically, the algorithm should place the shapes in the available space, biased towards the top. The solution it comes up with does not have to be 'perfect', but it should *always* be able to find a solution if one exists. Also I would really like to avoid using any pseudo-random numbers in this algorithm. I want it to always find the same solution given the same input, even if that solution isn't the best one.

I have found other topics relating to this, but all of them had to do with filling a rectangular space rather than an arbitrary space.

EDIT: oh, and the shapes CAN be flipped both horizontally and/or vertically, but not rotated. Forgot to mention this.

EDIT2: let me clarify. I don't want the space to be filled, I want to determine where the shapes should go given a finite number of them. They should default towards the top.

Comment: This problem seems like it might be NP-hard by a reduction from some sort of packing problem.

Answer (score 1):

Knuth wrote a paper called "Dancing Links" e.g. at http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs.DS/0011047 on a streamlined version of backtracking search. He uses it to e.g. tile a plane with polyonimoes. My guess is that this could be used to solve your problem - at some expense. I suspect that if a really general method existed to solve your problem, it could also be applied to Knuth's, which makes it unlikely that one will be found. Of course, your shapes are simpler than Knuth's, so perhaps there is some method particular to your problem which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As templatetypedef suspects, this problem is hard by a reduction from planar 1-in-3 SAT.

Dancing links is not appropriate unless you want all of the possible solutions and shapes don't repeat. Assuming that you want one solution where shapes can repeat, and that the instances are not too much larger than your sample, I would recommend dynamic programming. To tile a particular space, divide it into three subspaces A, B, C such that A and C are nonempty and no placement can overlap A and C simultaneously. Try to minimize the size of B. For each subset S of B (all 2<sup>|B|</sup> of them), attempt recursively to cover A union S and separately, C union (B minus S). If solutions are found for the same S, they can be combined. Otherwise, there is no solution. Handle the base cases with brute force.

Comment: The shapes do not repeat. There may be multiple 16x16s, or multiple instances of the shape shown above, but only a fixed amount.